# How can I create multiple javascript modal boxes with PHP & MySQL?

Tags: javascript, php, css, mysql, email

I am creating a staff portal, and part of the staff portal is to have a simple mailing system to be used between staff, and for the system to send emails to staff.

The way I want it to work is to list all the emails and the ones that haven't been read will be in bold and when they have been read they won't be in bold. The emails will all be in a table and sorted as needed, and then on the far right hand side there will be a button that says 'Open Message' and when the user clicks that I want it to open a modal box with the full message and the option to reply and all that stuff. I trailed it on 1 email and it worked and looked great, then the issues started when I added more emails. I thought the solution below would work, by renaming the modal box by using the mail ID I thought that would make it unique and allow me to have more than 1, but I need to get the data from the email in the modal box too, another reason I thought it would work inside the foreach loop. However it doesn't work at all.

```
        <table>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Sender</th>
                    <th>Subject</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th></th>
                  </tr>
                  <?php
                    foreach($mailResult as $mailRow) {
                      //Use Mail ID to retrieve the User who sent the original message
                      $mailUserSTMT = "SELECT `user_details_id`, `user_details_first_name`, `user_details_last_name` FROM `user_details` WHERE `user_details_id` IN (SELECT `user_mail_id` FROM `user_mail` WHERE user_details_id = :id)";

                      $fetchList = $dbh->prepare($mailUserSTMT);
                      $fetchList->bindValue(':id', $mailRow['user_mail_id']);
                      $fetchList->execute();
                      $mailUserRow = $fetchList->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                      $mailFromFullName = $mailUserRow['user_details_first_name']." ".$mailUserRow['user_details_last_name'];
                      $mail_id = $mailRow['user_mail_id'];
                      $btn = "popup".$mail_id;
                      $mod = "mod".$mail_id;
                      $modClose = "close".$mail_id;
                      if ($mailRow['user_mail_opened'] == "no") { $mailWeight = "bold"; } else { $mailWeight = "normal"; }
                      $mailStatus = ucfirst($mailRow['user_mail_status']);
                      echo "<tr style='word-wrap: break-word; text-align:center;''>";
                        echo "<td><p style='font-weight: ".$mailWeight.";'>".$mailFromFullName."</p></td>";
                        echo "<td><p style='font-weight: ".$mailWeight.";'>".$mailRow['user_mail_subject']."</p></td>";
                        echo "<td style='color:".$mailStatus."'><p style='font-weight: ".$mailWeight.";'>".$mailStatus."</p></td>";
                        echo "<td><button style='font-weight: ".$mailWeight.";' id='".$btn."'>Open Message</button></td>";
                      echo "</tr>";

                      ?>
                      <!-- The Modal -->
                      <div id="<?php echo $mod; ?>" class="modal">

                        <!-- Modal content -->
                        <div class="modal-content">
                          <span class="<?php echo $modClose; ?>">&times;</span>
                          <h4><b>From: </b><?= $mailFromFullName; ?></h4>
                          <p><b>Sent: </b><?= $mailRow['user_mail_timestamp']; ?></p>
                          <hr>
                          <table>
                            <tr>
                              <td><h5>Subject: <?= $mailRow['user_mail_subject']; ?></h5></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                 <td style='color:".$mailStatus."'>Urgency: <p style='font-weight: ".$mailWeight.";'>".$mailStatus."</p></td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                          <p><?= $mailRow['user_mail_message']; ?></p>
                        </div>

                      </div>
                      <script>
                      // Get the modal
                      var modal = document.getElementById("<?php echo $mod; ?>");

                      // Get the button that opens the modal
                      var btn = document.getElementById("<?php echo $btn; ?>");

                      // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
                      var span = document.getElementsByClassName("<?php echo $modClose; ?>")[0];

                      // When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
                      btn.onclick = function() {
                        modal.style.display = "block";
                      }

                      // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
                      span.onclick = function() {
                        modal.style.display = "none";
                      }

                      // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
                      window.onclick = function(event) {
                        if (event.target == modal) {
                          modal.style.display = "none";
                        }
                      }
                      </script>
                      <?php
                    }
                  ?>
                </table>
```

1 email now looks normal and the modal opens like normal (not displaying the right content though but that's another issue!), but the second email is just stuck underneath displayed all the time and won't hide away. I'll try and paste a screenshot of what it looks like

[Image of how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTjeV.png)

[How it should look but with more emails and obviously the modal with content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ro3SK.png)

Comment: User mail id mostly won't be unique. Add some integer to the id. Something like $mod = "mod".$mail_id.$i++;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the answer by looking around CodePen.io and found someone had done something similar so I used that and stuck with the original method of being unique as my original $mod was unique as each field had a different ID.

You can find the method I used here:

https://codepen.io/JackZelig/pen/VPdQXJ

```
<p>
  <button class="button" data-modal="modalOne">
    Contact Us
  </button>
</p>
<p>
  <button class="button" data-modal="modalTwo">
    Send Us Hate Mail
  </button>
</p>

<div id="modalOne" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="contact-form">
      <a class="close">&times;</a>
      <h2>Ask A Question</h2><br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="modalTwo" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="contact-form">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h2>Haters Gonna Hate</h2><br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```